# Is it dangerous to use C++ pointers like this in the stack implementation?

Tags: c++, stack

```
template <typename T>
class Stack {
private:
    int size;
    int max_s = 5;
    T def_val;
    T* arr;
public:
    Stack();
    bool IsEmpty();
    void push(T const&);
    T pop();
    int getMaxSize();
};

template <typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack()
{
    arr = new T[max_s];
    size = 0;
}

template <typename T>
void Stack<T>::push(T const& val)
{
    if (size == max_s)
    {
        max_s += 5;
        T* temp = arr;
        arr = nullptr;
        arr = new T[max_s];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = temp[i];
        }
        delete[] temp;
    }
    size++;
    arr[size - 1] = val;
}
```

If you check the `push()` function, I tried to increase the size of the pointer when the maximum size is reached. But I'm not sure if using pointers this way is inefficient and causing any memory leaks?

Edit: Code is updated, the main focus is the `push()` function as it was before.

Comment: One big improvement you can do is just replace `arr` with `temp` instead of copying back. For example `delete arr; arr = temp;` instead of `createAptr(arr);` and the following copy loop.

Comment: You will need to know [the rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to write a functional `Stack` class. The `Stack` class shown here does not respect it and will lead to problems later.

Comment: Considering adding a `private` function which is responsible for resizing your array. You will likely need to perform the same work in other functions.

Comment: Can you please explain in a bit more detail what `createAptr` is actually supposed to be doing? It definitely looks... strange. It allocates a new array for `arr` but also deletes whatever array the argument passed to it is pointing to? That seems like a weird set of things to do, and _very_ weird for it to be part of the class's public interface.

Comment: @NathanPierson createAptr function just does the resize process, i didn't know how to allocate more memory to a pointer so i tried to did it like giving the address to another pointer, delete it then assign new desired size to main pointer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thanks, I will check the rule. It was a bit weird to resize array with a public function though.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux , Because of resizing , i still need one copy loop in order to pass values to new allocated pointer. I've just updated the code, Is it correct now ? I mean just push function.

Comment: Weird implementation of `createAptr` make the code harder to understand (and maintain) because `pt` point to the same data as `arr`.

Comment: @OmerAdem That is much clearer now. I still recommend putting everything in the `if (size == max_s)` branch in a function.

Comment: In the resizing block, you should use a multiplication factor for the new size instead of adding some constant. I recommend doubling. Otherwise, pushing *n* elements has complexity of *O(n^2)*. This will not make a difference for 10 objects in  the stack, but if you try to push, say, one million objects, the code will become horribly slow.